# How does using a teleconverter affect the aperture of a lens?

Tags: aperture, teleconverter

I have hear that a teleconverter affects the apperture of a lens.  But I don´t know how to calculate it. 
Is there a formula to calculate how much will a 1.5X or 2X teleconverter affect apperture?